# group concat rows from another table joined by join table

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database, outer-join

i have 3 tables: visits, visit_Services, and services.

i want to select all visits and the services linked to it in one query !.

i tried

```
SELECT `v`.*, group_concat(s.name)
FROM `visits` `v`
left outer join `visit_service` vs on vs.visit_id = v.id
left outer join `services` s on s.id = vs.service_id
WHERE DATE(v.visit_date) = date(now())
```

problem is :-
 1. The result returns only 1 visit anf group_concat contains all services for all visits
 2. is this the best way to do it ? or is it better if i split order into 2 querys ?

thanks alot sof community

Comment: You forgot GROUP BY v.id

Comment: ouch. your are awesome ! and that solve the problem ! thanks @Gervs

Comment: I've put in an answer, so can mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `v`.*, group_concat(s.name)
FROM `visits` `v`
left outer join `visit_service` vs on vs.visit_id = v.id
left outer join `services` s on s.id = vs.service_id
WHERE DATE(v.visit_date) = date(now())
GROUP BY v.id
```

Note this is only if the full_group_by systemvariable is set to 0 (the default)